# Unable to generate long java serialversionuid in VSCode

Tags: java, serialization, visual-studio-code

The first problem I've found was that VSCode by default doesn't suggest anything to implement the serialversionuid. So I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1140#issuecomment-889191080) to activate that suggestion.

But now, the problem I have is that it doesn't matter which option you choose. It always generates a short uid for you.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can generate that uid? I've tried to generate it by hand using `serialver` but I can't get it to work.

The question would be, how do I make VSCode generate the long uid correctly?
And if it is not possible, how can I do it with `serialver` (or another solution)?

this is the relative path to my java file: `dahs-executor-v3\src\main\java\es\blabla\dahs\dsl\domain\data\v3\Measurement1m.java`

this is the relative path of my .class: `dahs-executor-v3\target\classes\es\blabla\dahs\dsl\domain\data\v3\Measurement1m.class`

(It's a Maven + Spring project)

Comment: Please read:  [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  Your problem should be described in words rather than pictures.  1) Image links break.  2) Visually impaired programmers will have difficult with them.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace** then click the second option `generated serial version ID`

[image]

Comment: Please read:  [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  Your solution should be described in words rather than pictures.  1) Image links break over time.  2) Visually impaired programmers will have difficult with them.

Comment: cleaning workspace didn't work for me. Still generating the short uid no matter what option you select.

Comment: @bibu3344. Have you tried the latest [CI Build](https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/jdt.ls/staging/?C=M;O=D) and test in an new project?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a novice programmer. I just keep VSCode up to date. I understand that plugins like Java update automatically. I have no idea what it is or how to use the CI BUILD you mention.

Comment: @bibu3344. Turn to this [page](https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/jdt.ls/staging/java-1.3.0-504/), download the vsix that's compatible with your OS. Then in VS Code, open Command Palette and choose `Extensions: install from vsix`, point to the .vsix file.

Comment: i just did it but still have the same problem. When i generate the uid i still get the short one.

Comment: @bibu3344. Create a new java project, does this question still exists?

Comment: i created a new java project and everything seems to work fine.